# Possible causes of chronic nasal congestion and dry lips?

Tags: nose

What could be the possible causes of chronic nasal congestion and dry lips? I have read that dry lips can be a result of breathing through one's mouth which can be directly linked to nasal congestion. Are the most likely causes possibly related to factors such as minimal exposure to sunlight, wintry weather with temperatures between 5 and 15 degrees centigrade? Otherwise, is it likely linked to daily, yet minimal exposure to common vehicle exhaust gases?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the site! Unfortunately your question in its current form is off topic, as it is asking for a personal medical assessment. I would encourage you to visit the help section, and if you can reword your question to be less personal, it can be nominated for reopening.

Comment: See also: https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/3962/breathing-through-one-nostril

Comment: I appreciate the edit, however I still believe that this is not really an answerable question, as it's either going to be very broad to address *all* causes of chronic nasal congestion, or people just speculating. I won't decline the reopen nomination, however, so if 5 other users believe it has merit it will be automatically reopened.

Comment: @JohnP I had a hunch that perhaps this is a cause of a nutritional deficiency as multiple more-delicate body-parts such as lips and nostrils are undergoing symptoms, rather than just the nose which is a very common condition. It is still pretty broad but I am still curious in this set of conditions, as to what their possible causes may be. I hope that users see this as worth answering.

Kind Regards,
Kreative